# How to give different tableViews same action between ViewControllers [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an app with multiple view controllers with a tableview in each of them. Each view controller's table have their own specific purpose, but I use the same swipe actions in each table. So far I have just been copying and pasting the same code for `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` and `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` in each table. This feels wrong and I know there should be a way where I can write the code once and use it throughout the app but I am not sure how to do this.

I have tried to extensions of `UITableView` but can not seem to use the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` or `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` functions in the extension file. What am I missing?

Here's the code for `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` which is just swipe to delete:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { (action, view, completionHandler) in

            if let item = self.dataSource.itemIdentifier(for: indexPath) {
                CoreDataManager.sharedManager.deleteItem(item)
            }

            completionHandler(true)
        }

        action.image = UIImage(named: "deleteSymbol")

        let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
        return configuration
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you declare below function as global function for the project and access any where you want
- You can modify function by adding parameter which you want to use when button clicked. just simply add parameter in function and pass data when you call

  ```
  func getSwipeAction(indexpath : IndexPath)-> UISwipeActionsConfiguration{
       let action = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "") { (action, 
      view, completionHandler) in

      completionHandler(true)
   }

   action.image = UIImage(named: "deleteSymbol")

   let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [action])
   return configuration
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can add these inner code in UITableView extension function and try to use it like that. You have to implement `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` or `leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` in each of your view controllers.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    return self.YourFunctionNameInExtension()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a protocol like **BaseTableViewProtocol** and in this protocol's extension you can write your code. So when you extend your tableView class from this protocol you can use the function. For example,

```
      protocol BaseTableViewProtocol { } 

      extension BaseTableViewProtocol { 
         func trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt() {
            //Something goes here
        }

         func leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt() {
            //Something goes here
        }
      }
```